# How to prevent icons from jumping down when sliding in a paragraph (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

Actually, this makes my question a lot more clear:

SETUP: I have 8 clickable icons. On bigger screens, they're grouped three in a row, three in a row, then 2 in a row. On mobile screens, the icons are one on top of the other, vertically. See this as an example: http://winter-construction.com/services/

PROBLEM: When I click an icon, I want a paragraph to toggle in explaining the icon. However, here's the catch: On mobile screens, I want the individual paragraph to toggle in below each individual icon. On bigger screens, I want the individual paragraph to toggle in below the row of icons, so they don't move around a lot.

How can I do this?? Would I append it to the icon in small screens, and append it to the row div in big screens? Code below:

HTML:

```
<!--------------- Services  ----------------------------->
<!----- ROW 1 ----->
<div class="row col-xs-12">
<!--- ICON 1 ----->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption1">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 1</h5>
  </div>
<!--- ICON 2 ----->       
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption2">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 2</h5>
  </div>
<!--- ICON 3 ----->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption3">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 3</h5>
  </div>
</div>

<!--- ROW 2 ----->
<div class="row col-xs-12">
<!--- ICON 4 ----->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption4">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 4</h5>
  </div>
 <!--- ICON 5 ----->  
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption4">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 5</h5>
  </div>
 <!--- ICON 6 ----->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption4">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 6</h5>
  </div>
</div>

<!----- ROW 3 ------->
<div class="row">
<!--- ICON 7 ----->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption4">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 7</h5>
  </div>
<!--- ICON 8 ----->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-12 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption4">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 8</h5>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="iconParagraphs" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 p-t-1">
    <div class="serviceOption1 text"> Text 1 </div>
    <div class="serviceOption2 text"> Text 2 </div>
    <div class="serviceOption3 text"> Text 3 </div>
    <div class="serviceOption4 text"> Text 4 </div>
    <div class="serviceOption5 text"> Text 5 </div>
    <div class="serviceOption6 text"> Text 6 </div>
    <div class="serviceOption7 text"> Text 7 </div>
    <div class="serviceOption8 text"> Text 8 </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS (just hides the paragraphs):

```
.text{
```

display: none;
     }

and my JQuery skeleton. This might not be the quickest way, so if there's something faster, let me know:

```
// When screen is less than 544 px, or 'mobile':
// When icon is clicked,
  $('a').click(function(){
// Get div with matching class of this element's ID
// Append that div after this anchor element
// When screen is 544px or greater:
// When icon is clicked,
// Get div with matching class of this element's ID
// Append it after this anchor element's row   
 }); // end SERVICES function
```

Comment: I haven't messed with JSFiddle before, so let me know if I linked it wrong.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle as you didn't include jQuery.

Comment: I guess each row is inside a div and share the same paragraph only changing it's text. (that's why there's no animation) But you could make a div.icon-row and a div.text-row and do the slideDown and slideUp magic of their children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/v0rhknmw/20/

I have added two `div` with class `block`. This contain a number of icon you want. After, i have created one div contain all your text you will appear below your icon.

It's a little ugly but it's work fine.

Please try:

```js
$('.m-b-2').click(function(){
  $.each($("#serviceOptionParagraph").find(".blockText"),function(){
    $(this).hide()
  })
  $(this).closest(".block").after($("#serviceOptionParagraph").show())
  $("#serviceOptionParagraph").find("."+$(this).attr("id")).show()
});
```

```css
/*--------------- Services Icons --------------------*/
i{
    cursor: pointer;
}

#serviceOptionParagraph{
    border: 1px solid #FF3B17;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3%;
    display: none;
}
.serviceOptionParagraph{
  display:none;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption1">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 1</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption2">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 2</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption3">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 3</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 text-xs-center m-b-2" id="serviceOption4">
    <a><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-5x m-b-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <h5>Icon 4</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="serviceOptionParagraph" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 p-t-1">
  <div class="serviceOption1 blockText"> 
    <img width="50%" src="http://cdn.winter-construction.com/wp-content/uploads/BIM-ReptileHouse1.jpg" >
  </div>
  <div class="serviceOption2 blockText"> Text 2</div>
  <div class="serviceOption3 blockText"> Text 3</div>
  <div class="serviceOption4 blockText"> Text 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @P. Frank, Would you mind helping me walk thru that so I understand?
// 1. When 'm-b-2- is clicked"
$('.m-b-2').click(function(){

// 2. Find the 'blockText' class in all the '#SOP' and hide it
  $.each($("#serviceOptionParagraph").find(".blockText"),function(){
    $(this).hide()
  })

// 3. Show the closest 'block' class from the clicked icon, and show it AFTER the '#SOP'.
  $(this).closest(".block").after($("#serviceOptionParagraph").show())

// 4. Show the ID attr. of this '#SOP"?
  $("#serviceOptionParagraph").find("."+$(this).attr("id")).show()
});

Thx for helping!!

Comment: Yes: `$.each($("#serviceOptionParagraph").find(".blockText"),function(){ $(this).hide() })` check elements with blockText class contain in this div and hide it `$(this).closest(".block").after($("#serviceOptionParagraph").show()) ` check if a parent element contain `block` class and add after it.  `$("#serviceOptionParagraph").find("."+$(this).attr("id")).show() });` i have add in your `blocktext` a class name with a same id name of the parent icon. This find element inside `serviceOptionParagraph` who contain the same class name of id icon you click (`$(this).attr("id")).show()`) and show it.